# Model validation with RemoteAttribute in ASP.NET Core does not POST the main form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple ASP.NET Core MVC application, my view model has a property with [Remote] validation attribute which works fine, almost...

```
        [Remote("CustomName", "Index",
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid name.",
        AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken,UserId",
        HttpMethod = "post"
        )]
        public string CustomName { get; set; }
```

Here is my remote validation action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CustomName(Guid UserId, string CustomName)
    {
        // Some logic which is fine and works...
        //.....
        //...
        //..
        //.

        return new JsonResult(true);
    }
```

I have standard way of form implementation with POST action which is working fine. Post request fires the correct controller action...etc.

My problem is, when I have this Remote attribute, my form's POST action does not work in first time. When I clicked the button, first Remote Validation action works but not the original post action. After a second click to button, my form's post action works fine.

I could not understand the reason and fine a way to solve this issue. What might the reason be? And solution?

*My application is ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: How long does it take for your remote validation action to execute? That would be my first suspicion. This definitely isn’t the normal or expected behavior with the `[Remote()]` attribute.

Comment: @JeremyCaney just milliseconds... Not a big validation action exists. Kind of name== "John Doe"